# Is (A -> B) /\ (C -> D) <: (A /\ C) -> (B /\ D)?

Tags: subtype, type-theory

Is (A -> B) /\ (C -> D) a subtype of (A /\ C) -> (B /\ D)?

It seems like it shouldn't be, simply on account of -> being contravariant, but I can't find a good counterexample.

If it is, how can I derive this?

If not, what would a counterexample be?

(To clarify, I'm using /\ for intersection here.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about mathematical logic, not computer programming.

Comment: A pair type is never a subtype of a function type, at least according to any notion of subtyping I've seen.

Comment: It's a question about subtyping. There are plenty of type-theory and subtyping questions on stack overflow.

Comment: Andras: It's an intersection type. (A -> B) /\ (C -> D) is trivially a subtype of A -> B, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types are in a subtype relation, precisely *because* of contravariance. The union would be a supertype of A and C, so would violate contravariance.

Recall the subtyping rule for functions, which is contravariant in the domain type:

T → U  <:  T' → U' iff T' <: T and U <: U'

For intersection types, you also have a distributivity rule over arrow types:

(T → U) ∧ (T → V)  =  T → (U ∧ V)

And of course we have the usual elimination rules for intersection types:

T ∧ U  <:  T
T ∧ U  <:  U

Plugging these four rules together, you can easily derive the subtyping you're asking about:

(A → B) ∧ (C → D)
<: (by contravariance and left elimination)
((A ∧ C) → B) ∧ (C → D)
<: (by contravariance and right elimination)
((A ∧ C) → B) ∧ ((A ∧ C) → D)
<: (by distributivity)
(A ∧ C) → (B ∧ D)

FWIW, with union types, you also have the dual distributivity rule:

(U → T) ∨ (V → T)  =  (U ∨ V) → T

With that, you can analogously derive:

(A → B) ∨ (C → D) <: (A ∨ C) → (B ∨ D)

Comment: Shouldn't U' <: U be U <: U' as the codomain is covariant in function subtyping?

Comment: @k4rtik, oops, yes, fixed.

Comment: I don't think `(U → T) ∨ (V → T) = (U ∨ V) → T` is correct. It should be `(U → T) ∨ (V → T) = (U ∧ V) → T`